# Inline PDF attachment - Doesn't work on FF

Tags: php, inline, attachment

My php script outputs this code:

```
<object height="100%" width="100%" id="help" align="left" data="file_helper.php" type="application/pdf">
    Click <a href="file_helper.php">here</a> to view help.
</object>
```

The definition for file_helper.php without parameters is the following:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Content-Length: '.<length of binary pdf file>);
header('Expires: 0');
echo '<binary pdf file>'
```

The problem is that this works on Internet Explorer, Chrome.
In Firefox it works only locally, but not on a remote side.

On Firefox I get instead: Click **here** to view help, with working href.

But I want to display file inline. Is there something I do incorrectly?

EDIT: Android Chrome, Android FF do not display pdf; FF on Ubuntu displays, FF on Windows does not display.

Comment: not all browsers support pdf the same way. That's life.

Comment: Sounds like FF doesn't support embedded PDF. The whole point of having the link is to provide a fallback when it's not supported. So it's working as designed.

Comment: not all browsers support webview for pdf files. for android you can use http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://mypdffile.com/pdf.pdf